# Json file format error in yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2

Hi guys i am using a `Jquery` plugin for displaying events in calendar and i can see the plugin calendar on my view file just the problem is that i can not create valid `json` format file for the plugin

This is the format given in the plugin demo page

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: text/json');
echo '[';
$separator = "";
$days = 16;
echo '  { "date": "1314579600000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Last Year" },';
echo '  { "date": "1377738000000", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Next Year"},';
for ($i = 1 ; $i < $days; $i= 1 + $i * 2) {
  echo $separator;
  $initTime = (intval(microtime(true))*1000) + (86400000 * ($i-($days/2)));
  echo '    { "date": "'; echo $initTime; echo '", "type": "meeting", "title": "Project '; echo $i; echo ' meeting",   },';
  echo '    { "date": "'; echo $initTime+3600000; echo '", "type": "demo", "title": "Project '; echo $i; echo ' demo" },';

  $separator = ",";
 }
  echo ']';
?>
```

What should be my `controller` code to display the data. I tried the format in the answer below but it still doesnt display the data properly.

I think something is wrong in the `json` format i am receiving on frontend. First image is my localhost where i am receiving data and the second one is plugin demo and array format is a bit different i guess and thats the problem

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a controller and put inside an 'event' action?

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;


class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionEvent()
    {
       /* Input parameters */
       $limit = \Yii::$app->request->get('limit');
       $year = \Yii::$app->request->get('year');
       $month = \Yii::$app->request->get('month');
       $day = \Yii::$app->request->get('day');

       /* Fill data */
       $data = [];
       $data[] = [ 'date' => '1314579600000', 'type' => 'meeting', 'title' => 'Test Last Year' ]; 

       /*
       ...
       ... other data ...
       ...
       */

        /* Prepare the content output*/
        \Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($data);
    }
}
```

and finally call the action:

```
$("#eventCalendarNewWindow").eventCalendar({
        eventsjson: "<?php echo \yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/event']) ?>",
        openEventInNewWindow: true,
        showDescription: true // also it can be false
});
```

Comment: i tried that before but the problem with that was i could get the response back in the browser fine but it doesnt display anything on the event date. It still displays there are no events on that date thats why i tried this format.

Comment: maybe is description field (now missing in the code) mandatory?

Comment: @ FabrizioCaldarelli no thats not it. I have tried without Description and setting it to false.

Comment: have you checked with firebug if there is some javascript error?

Comment: i checked with google chrome and no error and also checked with firebug console is clear no error or warning

Comment: ok there is something wrong with the format data is received at the frontend. I checked on the plugin demo page and my page. i dont know how to solve it but i am uploading the screenshot and may be you could help me about that